# Custom Loss Function: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow

While implementing a custom loss function I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

my custom loss function looks like this:

```
""" now combine the layers """
combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([modelRNN.output, modelCNN.output])

final_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(combined) #ff kijken of dit slim is
final_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(final_dense)

final_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[modelCNN.input, modelRNN.input], outputs=final_dense)

targets = np.asarray(match_train).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
targets = tf.convert_to_tensor(targets, np.float32)
logits = final_dense
pos_weight = (45000 - 4539) / 4539


custom_loss = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    targets,
    logits,
    pos_weight,
    )


final_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                    loss=custom_loss,
                    metrics=['accuracy'])

final_model.fit([MNIST_train, RNN_train], match_train, epochs=1, batch_size=100)
```

The target data is an array with shape(45000,1) with boolean values. I understand that a bool is not allowed but I thought I converted it back to a tensor with the line:

```
targets = tf.convert_to_tensor(targets, np.float32)
```

Comment: Please see the documentation first https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits
First of all, targets and logits must have the same type and shape

Comment: I checked whether the type() is the same, targets and logits are both tensors. I also checked the shape, for which I received an error beforehand. This should be working out too.

Lastly, I converted all the boolean values in the original match_train dataset to 0's and 1's. 

I don't understand the error that using a tensor as a boolean value is not allowed. Where do I have Boolean values?

Comment: The error message does not say that you have boolean values.

Comment: " I don't understand the error that using a tensor as a boolean value is not allowed." It means that you passed a tensor where a boolean value was expected.